# XML sitemap goes to 404 page

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I have installed wpseo by yoast and it doesn't list all the links inside sitemap.
It just only indexing the xml sitemap.

for eg:

```
http://domain.com/sitemap_index.xml list the following xml files.
When i click any one of the following xml file it goes to 404 page.

http://domain.com/post-sitemap.xml
http://domain.com/page-sitemap.xml
```

The following is my nginx config:

```
rewrite ^/sitemap\.xml$ /sitemap_index.xml permanent;
rewrite ^/([a-z]+)?-?sitemap\.xsl$ /index.php?xsl=$1 last;
rewrite ^/sitemap_index\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;
```

Reference:

http://kb.yoast.com/article/16-my-sitemap-is-giving-a-404-error-what-should-i-do

http://kb.yoast.com/article/123-xml-sitemap-errors

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-yoasts-wordpress-seo-sitemap-404-error/

http://kb.yoast.com/article/96-enable-xml-sitemaps-in-the-wordpress-seo-plugin

Answer (score 0):

I tried this from [htpcbeginner](http://www.htpcbeginner.com/yoast-seo-sitemap-blank-nginx-solved/) and it worked perfectly.

- Am using Ubuntu 14.04.3 x64, Nginx 1.4.6
- WordPress 4.4.2

Place the following lines inside **location block** in yoursite.com file in
`/etc/nginx/sites-avaliable` and don't forget to relink it to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` folder.

```
#This rewrite redirects sitemap.xml to sitemap_index.xml, which is what Yoast's WordPress SEO plugin generates.
rewrite ^/sitemap\.xml$ /sitemap_index.xml permanent;
 

#This rewrite ensures that the styles are available for styling the generated sitemap.
rewrite ^/([a-z]+)?-?sitemap\.xsl$ /index.php?xsl=$1 last;

#These rewrites rule are generated by Yoast's plugin for Nginx webserver.

rewrite ^/sitemap_index\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;
```

- You should change the permalinks to `/%postname%/`.
- Don't forget to restart Nginx server.
  `sudo service nginx restart`
  That should work with you. Goodluck.